# Maximum number of elements in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

How can I store more than 2^128 elements in an array in java.

I tried `Integer.MAX_value` but this is not the range I want. I want more numbers.

This is the ERROR in using (Integer.MAX_VALUE):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array
>   size exceeds VM limit.

Comment: Even if you could store them, do you have that much memory available for the VM.init ?

Comment: "How can I store more than 2^128 elements in an array in java." - You can't.  You will need to use a different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays internally use integers (int not Integer) for index, the max size is limited by the max size of integers. So theoretically it is 2^31-1 = 2147483647, which is Integer.MAX_VALUE.

But in recent HotSpot JVM it has been observed that the max size of array can be Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5.